# document.getElementsByName missing from Gecko/Firefox on SVG documents

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, gecko

I have an SVG document in which I am using JavaScript to highlight elements on mouseover. My elements all have names - some elements have the same name because, although they appear multiple times, they logically refer to the same thing. When one instance of a replicated element is moused over, I want them all to highlight.

To effect the highlighting, I look up the name of the element being moused over. Then, I call `document.getElementsByName()` to find all the elements sharing that name. With the returned array of elements, I iteratively apply the appropriate style to highlight.

That works great on WebKit and fails on Gecko - the latter informs me that `getElementsByName` is undefined. Which, looking at the function table for `document` is indeed the case: `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName`, `getElementsByTagNameNS` are all there; `getElementsByName` is missing.

Any ideas as to why Gecko leaves this selector out? Google was unhelpful in this matter (though I may have asked the wrong questions).

Any suggestions for a compact workaround to Gecko's lack of support for this selector? I'd greatly prefer not having to hijack the class attribute or (worse) generate unique ids for my repeated instances to accomplish the task.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer to your specific question about Gecko's support for the selector, but I am curious why you don't use CSS: `circle[name=blah]:hover` - is browser support lacking for CSSS hover in SVG?  I'm also wondering if jQuery's selector system bridges this inadequacy (or it's *just different* with SVG).

Comment: @peterorpeter: the OP wants to highlight *all* elements with a given name when *one* of them is hovered. Can CSS do that?

Comment: What version of FF? Is `querySelectorAll` not in the function table?

Comment: @Roatin Marth. Brilliant suggestion. `querySelectorAll` works perfectly on both Gecko and WebKit. Please repost as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks!

Comment: @peteorpeter. I like your suggestion in general; in this particular instance it will not work as well as Roatin Marth's. I have SVG documents with hundreds of elements. Some of them are replicated instances (have the same name); most are unique. CSS would work, but would be hugely long, as I'd have to have shape[name=blah]:hover over and over for each distinct (set of) element(s).

Comment: Good point, @Roatin Marth and @M. Anthony Aiello. I had realized that  extra logic was required when reading the OP but lost that point amidst my curiosity about how CSS interacts with SVG.  (I don't believe it's possible without scripting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@roatin-marth put me on the path to an answer, here, but never posted as an answer. I thought I would capture his suggestion here in case it helps anyone else.

Using `querySelectorAll` provides the compact workaround I was seeking — it is must more robust (and more flexible) than `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: is an SVG document also a (X)HTML document?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName

FTA:

> The name attribute is only applicable to (X)HTML documents. The method returns all elements with a name attribute, such as  or  or even if name is placed on elements which do not support a name attribute at all.

Comment: Probably not, given that the document starts with `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>` So I suppose it's not surprising that it didn't work. The frustrating/surprising part really was that all of the other `getElement*` selectors seemed to be there.

Comment: If you serve your SVG with the XHTML MIME type then your document will at least get the getElementsByName method. But that doesn't mean that it will still display as SVG, or return the elements that you want...